# RSA-engine could not be loaded by openssl configuration file

Tags: c, openssl, php-openssl, openssl-engine

Well I am new to engines in openssl . I have implemented a rsa engine. When i load it using envirmental variables by following command it works.

```
openssl engine -t -c rsaa-engine
openssl rsautl -encrypt -in msg.txt -pubin -inkey pubkey-B.pem -engine rsaa-engine -out cip.bin
```

The C code for the engine is :

```c
static const char *engine_rsa_id = "myengine";
static const char *engine_rsa_name = "RSAX";
static RSA_METHOD struct_rsa = {
  NULL,
  NULL,
  NULL,
  NULL,
  NULL,
  NULL,
  NULL,
  NULL,
  NULL,
  RSA_FLAG_CACHE_PUBLIC | RSA_FLAG_CACHE_PRIVATE,
  NULL,
  NULL,
  NULL
};

static int bind (ENGINE * e, const char *id)
{
  const RSA_METHOD *meth1;

  if (!ENGINE_set_id (e, engine_rsa_id) ||
    !ENGINE_set_name (e, engine_rsa_name) ||
    !ENGINE_set_RSA (e, &struct_rsa))
  return 0;

  meth1 = RSA_PKCS1_SSLeay ();
  e_rsax_rsa.rsa_pub_enc = eng_rsa_pub_enc;
  e_rsax_rsa.rsa_pub_dec = eng_rsa_pub_dec;
  e_rsax_rsa.rsa_priv_enc = eng_rsa_priv_enc;
  e_rsax_rsa.rsa_priv_dec = eng_rsa_priv_dec;
  e_rsax_rsa.bn_mod_exp = meth1->bn_mod_exp;
  e_rsax_rsa.finish = meth1->finish;

  return 1;
}

IMPLEMENT_DYNAMIC_BIND_FN (bind) 
IMPLEMENT_DYNAMIC_CHECK_FN ()
```

I am having problem in loading engine by using configuration file. In `openssl.conf` file I have added this:

```
openssl_conf = openssl_init
[ openssl_init ]
 engines = engine_section
[engine_section]
rsaa-engine = rsaa_section
[rsaa_section]
engine_id =rsaa-engine
dynamic_path =/usr/lib/powerpc-linux-gnu/openssl-1.0.0/engines/librsaa-engine.so
#dynamic_path =/home/engines/engine-rsa/librsaa-engine.so (symlink to this  location basically)
default_algorithms = RSA
```

I have added these lines in configuration file but when I try to encrypt or decrypt using following command

```
openssl rsautl -encrypt -in msg.txt -pubin -inkey pubkey-B.pem -out cip.bin
```

I get following errors

```
Error configuring OpenSSL
4159182024:error:260AC089:engine routines:INT_CTRL_HELPER:invalid cmd name:eng_ctrl.c:131:
4159182024:error:260AB089:engine routines:ENGINE_ctrl_cmd_string:invalid cmd name:eng_ctrl.c:311:
4159182024:error:260BC066:engine routines:INT_ENGINE_CONFIGURE:engine configuration error:eng_cnf.c:191:section=rsaa_section, name=HOME, value=.
4159182024:error:0E07606D:configuration file routines:MODULE_RUN:module initialization error:conf_mod.c:223:module=engines, value=engine_section, retcode=-1
```

Comment: Also see Richard Levitte's [Engine Building Lesson 1: A Minimum Useless Engine](https://www.openssl.org/blog/blog/2015/10/08/engine-building-lesson-1-a-minimum-useless-engine/) and [Engine Building Lesson 2: An Example MD5 Engine](https://www.openssl.org/blog/blog/2015/11/23/engine-building-lesson-2-an-example-md5-engine/) from the OpenSSL Blog.